# Transfer execution of a process from thread1 to thread2

Tags: c++, multithreading

Just a theoretical question (may not be even practical), asked just out of curiosity.

**How can I transfer execution of a process `LongComputation()` from  `ThreadProcess1()` to `ThreadProcess2()`without breaking the flow of the process? Is it possible?** Here, ThreadProcess1() is time critical and LongComputation() is also important but not time-critical. Frankly, I fail to understand how to inject a running process to another secondary thread without breaking the process nor the current thread, with the available c++ concurrency toolkits

**Here's a practical scenario :** ThreadProcess1() is timebound, and finds that `LongComputation()` is taking more time than the set timout, it wants to transfer this process to another thread but wants to continue execution of the remaining code.

```
void LongComputation() {
    /* ... */
}

void ThreadProcess1() {
    /* start LongComputation()  

       tranfer the incomplete LongComputation() 

       to process2 for completing */
}

void ThreadProcess2() {

}
```

Comment: you should not need to do this, use `mutex` so OS do this for you.

Comment: @appleapple: Accepted, but is it possible anyhow? How can mutex help here?

Comment: sorry I misread your Q. mutex cannot help here.

Comment: still. you should not need to do this, can you explain more?

Comment: e.g. why you cannot spawn another thread to run `LongComputation`

Comment: @appleapple: Include a practical scenario in query. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: any reason not use separate thread for `LongComputation`? it'd be *much* easier.

Comment: @appleapple: Accepted, but still is it theoretically possible?

Comment: yes, it theoretically possible. Thread is not something magic, you can theoretically swap the context to another thread. Depends on the complexity of `LongComputation`, maybe not at standard or even c++ level, though

Comment: note that by doing so, you're basically re-implement the OS level thread.

Comment: In reality, wouldn't it just be better to give `thread1` a proper timeout time?

Comment: @Chipster: threads1 checks if LongCompu was held beyond set timeout, if affirmative, it wants to transfer it to thread2 but continue its own exec, it wont terminate, needs to inject the process to another thread.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly you can spawn a thread for `longComputation()` and then try to join it for a set time. After that time elapses just continue to the end of the function (and optionally try to join again).

Comment: @ark1974 I understand that. My point is by the time you take execution time to transfer to another thread, wouldn't that eat time that you could spend finishing the calculation instead? In that case, why wouldn't it be better to let the original thread just keep working and extend its timeout time and allow it to finish properly? All processes that depend on the calculation will still have to wait anyway, and you still need a thread to run the calculation. So why transfer?

Comment: @Chipster: Lets say Thread1 is dealing with reading frames from media files and don't want to stress beyond the frame-time anyway; the LongCompu is important but not time critical.

Comment: What do you mean by "stress"? It's a thread: It can run on its own without disturbing your `main()`'s execution. It could tax your CPU though. Are you wanting to immediately pick up execution, or resume it later at a better time?

Comment: Alright, if ``t1`` is dealing with important data that needs to be quickly computed, such as rendering frames, don't have blocking work in that thread. Create a worker thread ``t2`` and do all your work from there. You could even trigger the work on ``t2`` from ``t1`` and wait a variable amount of time for completion before waiting until the next loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is just off the top of my head, on mobile and can't test. Please rightfully tear me to shreds for posting it as an answer if I'm wrong. I'm fairly sure this could be done (hypothetically) by literally just transferring CPU state. Even from user mode, easy. Suspend `t1` and grab its context via `GetThreadContext` (on Windows). Then do the same for `t2` and use `SetThreadContext` to swap out the state. You will need a manager thread for this scenario, but it's purely hypothetical anyway as it would never be the best solution in the real world. All this would really do is slow things down by trigerring an interrupt to set another thread to resume code we were already executing. In reality, what you probably want is an [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/event-objects) where you can signal `t2` to do some work for `t1` if it's taking too long.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but lets see if some others have different ideas.

Comment: If you want a more in depth response you need to reframe your question, it makes no sense. If it's a purely educational question of whether one thread can be swapped to another than its been answered. This is also what the thread scheduler of your OS is constantly doing. Please include a specific example of what you want and, more importantly, why you feel that it's the best solution.

Comment: Frankly, I fail to understand how to inject a running process to another secondary thread without breaking the process nor the current thread, with the available c++ concurrency toolkits.

Comment: @user207421: So may be the short answer is "No. It is not possible", so that I can accept it as answer ( or not!). But will the future programmers on SO not satisfied later?

Comment: Here is the issue, some of your questions are like asking how many decibels are emitted by the number 42. It just doesn't make sense, so it's difficult to answer. This is why I suggested you reframe your question earlier. As a purely theoretical question as to whether one thread can switch itself to another, it's been answered.

Comment: Note that if we're talking about `std::thread` objects, they can be `std::swap` ed as well. Not sure it's exactly the same thing as suspending the thread and switching its context, though. However, I just thought I still might mention it just in case.